# Fill all cells of grid with selected color using vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

I created a pixel art maker using vanilla JavaScript in which a user can draw on a grid with a color of his or her choice. I would like to add a button that allows for filling the grid with a single color.

In the jQuery version of my project, I achieved this with:

```
 $(".quick-fill").click(function() {
   const color = $('.color-picker').val();
   pixelCanvas.children().find('td').css('background-color', color);
 });
```

I tried changing that code to vanilla javaScript, and I think I'm only off by one line.

```
 quickFill.addEventListener('submit', function() {
   const color = document.querySelector('.color-picker').value;
   pixelCanvas.table.children.style('background-color', color); <- wrong!
 });
```

How would I select all the cells of the grid and fill them in with color?

(Here's my full current code for reference: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/nataliecardot/pen/MQRxJZ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to iterate over all of them:

```
pixelCanvas.querySelectorAll('td').forEach(td => td.style.backgroundColor = color);
```

But there's another problem. The `<input type="submit" class="quick-fill"` is *outside* of a form. Probably make a click handler instead of a submit handler:

```
quickFill.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const color = document.querySelector('.color-picker').value;
  pixelCanvas.querySelectorAll('td').forEach(td => 
    td.style.backgroundColor = color;
  );
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vRJwOw

Comment: I tried wrapping the input element inside form tags, but strangely, the submit handler still wouldn't work after replacing the incorrect line with the one you suggested to use to iterate over the tds. 
I used the code you suggested in the CodePen (slightly different than what you have here), but for some reason when I tested it in my browser, hitting 'fill' refreshed the page (though doesn't happen in your CodePen), so I added e.preventDefault(); (with e as a parameter, of course), which fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: Oh, I see why submit handler won't work. This is from MDN: "Note that submit is fired only on the form element, not the button or submit input. (Forms are submitted, not buttons.)"